# MySqlconnection does not contain a definition for Connection, CommandText, Prepare, or ExecuteNonquery

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working with the tutorial at http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/, I believe I have followed the steps exactly, yet I am getting these errors.  I have added MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity to the references yet it still doesn't allow me to use it.  I have googled the issue and can't seem to get a clear answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.Types;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace Practice
{
    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string cs = @"server=111.111.11.111; userid=11111111;password=111111;database=anydatabase";

            MySqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                conn.Open();

                MySqlConnection cmd = new MySqlConnection();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INT0 players(Anyone) VALUES(@Anyone)";
                cmd.Prepare();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Anyone New");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: (0)", ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put your user id and password here.

Comment: Even if he moves the user name password to the .Config file I am wondering if he stepped thru the code and got an error after the conn.Open()..this whold connection string looks a bit off but I am only taking a quick look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `MySqlCommand`.

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
```

Comment: That was it, solved all the issues right off the bat.  Guess the tutorial is off a bit, have to work around that